# How to insert data to MySQL with auto-incremented column(field)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, auto-increment

I've created a table with a primary key and enabled `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.authors (
    hostcheck_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    instance_id INT,
    host_object_id INT,
    check_type INT,
    is_raw_check INT,
    current_check_attempt INT,
    max_check_attempts INT,
    state INT,
    state_type INT,
    start_time datetime,
    start_time_usec INT,
    end_time datetime,
    end_time_usec INT,
    command_object_id INT,
    command_args VARCHAR(25),
    command_line VARCHAR(100),
    timeout int,
    early_timeout INT,
    execution_time DEC(18,5),
    latency DEC(18,3),
    return_code INT,
    output VARCHAR(50),
    long_output VARCHAR(50),
    perfdata VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Then, with the query below, I've tried "" and "1" for the first value but it doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO  test.authors VALUES ('1','1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1',
'2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929','2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','',
'/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping  5','30','0','4.04159','0.102','1',
'PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms','',
'rta=2.860000m=0%;80;100;0');
```

So, how to insert data to **MySQL** with auto-incremented column(field)?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In order to take advantage of the auto-incrementing capability of the column, do not supply a value for that column when inserting rows. The database will supply a value for you.

```
INSERT INTO test.authors (
   instance_id,host_object_id,check_type,is_raw_check,
   current_check_attempt,max_check_attempts,state,state_type,
   start_time,start_time_usec,end_time,end_time_usec,command_object_id,
   command_args,command_line,timeout,early_timeout,execution_time,
   latency,return_code,output,long_output,perfdata
) VALUES (
   '1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1','2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929',
   '2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','',
   '/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping  5','30','0','4.04159',
   '0.102','1','PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms',
   '','rta=2.860000m=0%;80;100;0'
);
```

Comment: but the query you pasted for me you put value for primery key??

Comment: @SalmanRaza: no, look: the column "hostcheck_id" is missing from the query I suggested. I gave values for only 23 columns but there are 24 columns in the table. I guess Adrian's suggestion would work too, but I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: @Celada great thing about this site - you learn something even when your own answer is correct :-)

Comment: @All thanks for your reply ! it help me out i pass '0' value for primery key column

Answer (score 189):

Set the auto increment field to NULL or 0 if you want it to be auto magically assigned...

Comment: This works for me unlike skipping autoincrement column value.

Comment: Prefer `NULL`, as `0`'s behaviour can be affected by [NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero).

Comment: yup, this is how you can insert using a select instead of values

Answer (score 37):

The `default` keyword works for me:

```
mysql> insert into user_table (user_id, ip, partial_ip, source, user_edit_date, username) values 
(default, '39.48.49.126', null, 'user signup page', now(), 'newUser');
---
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

I'm running `mysql --version` 5.1.66:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib **5.1.66**, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1
```

Comment: You can leave the column names out as long as the values match the order of the columns. It may be considered bad practice to do it, but for a one-time quick insert it's a good solution.

Comment: @Shahar This is much better than leaving the column name out. By this way, you have an better idea of what is going on in your SQL

Comment: @user3284463 I totally agree, I just think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the order may match NOW but won't necessarily match when the sql is run LATER.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for potgres 10.10 is not permitted to put 0 or null values, but with default it works;

Answer (score 13):

Check out [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) post

According to it

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL
>   assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly
>   assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

Answer (score 11):

I see three possibilities here that will help you insert into your table without making a complete mess but **"specifying"** a value for the **AUTO_INCREMENT** column, since you are supplying all the values you can do either one of the following options.

First approach (Supplying **NULL**):

```
INSERT INTO test.authors VALUES (
 NULL,'1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1','2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929',
 '2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','',
 '/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping  5','30','0','4.04159',
 '0.102','1','PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms',
 '','rta=2.860000m=0%;80;100;0'
);
```

Second approach (Supplying **''** {Simple quotes / apostrophes} although it will give you a warning):

```
INSERT INTO test.authors VALUES (
 '','1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1','2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929',
 '2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','',
 '/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping  5','30','0','4.04159',
 '0.102','1','PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms',
 '','rta=2.860000m=0%;80;100;0'
);
```

Third approach (Supplying **default**):

```
INSERT INTO test.authors VALUES (
 default,'1','67','0','0','1','10','0','1','2012-01-03 12:50:49','108929',
 '2012-01-03 12:50:59','198963','21','',
 '/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping  5','30','0','4.04159',
 '0.102','1','PING WARNING -DUPLICATES FOUND! Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 2.86 ms',
 '','rta=2.860000m=0%;80;100;0'
);
```

Either one of these examples should suffice when inserting into that table as long as you include all the values in the same order as you defined them when creating the table.

Answer (score 2):

For **auto-incremented column(field)**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You can use `NULL` or `0` to insert **an auto-incremented value** as shown below:

```sql
                        -- Here
INSERT INTO person VALUES (NULL, "John", "Smith")
```

```sql
                        -- Here
INSERT INTO person VALUES (0, "John", "Smith")
```

Comment: default is ok too

Answer (score -1):

I used something like this to type only values in my SQL request.
There are too much columns in my case, and im lazy.

```
insert into my_table select max(id)+1, valueA, valueB, valueC.... from my_table;
```