# MySql using a select and insert or update in an IF ELSE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql is it possible to do something like this in a statement that is to be used in PHP and not in a stored procedure or anything else.

`if(select count(*) from reports where empId = 9 and repId = 10 = 0,'Do an insert',' Update the existing row')// Just for example`

I know about the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` thing. But I cannot use that.

```
CREATE TABLE `reports` (
    `genId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `designation` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `empId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `repId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`genId`)
)
```

Comment: "But I cannot use that." why not? Fix whatever it is that's keeping you from using that.

Comment: You can use [Replace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10095787/1906094) maybe?