# multiple rows update or insert mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a table like this,

```
   id   |   option_name   |   value   |   user_id
----------------------------------------------
   1    |   name          |  Joe      |   1
----------------------------------------------
   2    |   age           |   30      |   1
----------------------------------------------
   3    |   sex           |   male    |   1
----------------------------------------------
   4    |   name          |  Jane     |   2
----------------------------------------------
   5    |   age           |   28      |   2
----------------------------------------------
   6    |   sex           |  female   |   2
----------------------------------------------
```

I want to update all rows corresponding of `user_id` and `option_name`.

If `user_id == 3`, when i submit form with `option_name` (`name`,`sex`,`age`) as fields,  if there is no rows with `user_id == 3` then insert rows but if rows exist i want to update those row with new values for `value` field.

Please check my code: http://pastebin.com/THQdYpix

I want to reduce query steps in my code, any idea?

Comment: And your specific question about that task is? We won't do it all for you.

Comment: You could give us also the code you are working on.

Comment: Show some code what you have tried??..

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql: if value exists UPDATE else INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095680/mysql-if-value-exists-update-else-insert)

Answer (score 0):

First check if it updates or note if the mysql_query() returns false then you can use insert query and execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).If you want to do this in a single statement, I would recommend using the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, someothervalue) VALUES (1, 'hi mom') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE someothervalue = 'hi mom';
```

The initial INSERT statement will execute if there is no existing record with the specified key value (either primary key or unique). If a record already exists, the following UPDATE statement (someothervalue = 3) is executed.

Comment: @user3643568this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work.

```
REPLACE INTO `table1`
( `name`,`sex`,`age` )
VALUES
( 'Mark', '29', 'male' )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id=3;
```