# How to insert values into database in java

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, insert

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user (userid, username, password, lastname, firstname, "
            + "middlename, birthdate, gender, address, email, contact, "
            + "marital_status, religion) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password.toString()); //chartype
        pst.setString(3, lastName);
        pst.setString(4, firstName);
        pst.setString(5, middleName);
        pst.setString(6, birthdate);
        pst.setString(7, gender1);
        pst.setString(8, address1);
        pst.setString(9, email1);
        pst.setLong(10, mobile);
        pst.setString(11, status1);
        pst.setString(12, religion1);
        pst.execute();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I have 13 columns  and userid is autoincrement. But I don't know how do that you don't need to put the user id.

And I got this error. And I want Auto Increment ID. So no need to input right?

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: you can remove that field since it is auto_increment column or just pass `NULL` value. eg, `VALUES(NULL, ?,?,.....`

Comment: Send `NULL` or remove the `userid` column. I would also suggest that you use [`INSERT INTO...SET`](http://milov.nl/2836) syntax to improve readability.

Comment: Avoid user_id in insert command or just pass `null`.

Comment: You have got 13 columns name in your INSERT code but there are 12 VALUES on your sql code. Delete userid column INSERT code or add null value before all question marks on VALUES code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert values to AutoInc column, so just remove it from query:

```
insert into user(userName, password,...) values (and your values here)
```

Comment: so I going to make primary key the username?

Comment: @JeraldPunx nope, your `userid` will be auto incremented by the DB as you specified.

Comment: do you know how to insert char[] for my password? cause when I use `password.toString()` the password on my localhost/phpadmin is different...

Comment: actually storing password as plain text is bad idea. So you need to store just a hash (sha1 e.g)

Comment: no i don't need that... this is just a school project... not for company... do you know how to insert char?

Comment: why is your password of char[] type? Why not string?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "userid" from the list of columns if you don't intend to supply a value to it.

I.e. `INSERT INTO user (username, password, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying 13 columns in your `INSERT`, but only 12 placeholders in the `VALUES` clause. The number of columns and values must match. Either you need to remove the `userid` column from your `INSERT`, or you need to add an additional placeholder (or literal value) to set its value.

Answer (score 0):

Is your database MySQL? If yes, you could refer to this post about inserting value to auto incremented column.
[How to insert data to MySQL having auto incremented primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753371/how-to-insert-data-to-mysql-having-auto-incremented-primery-key)