# trying to add a new user and I got this error

Tags: php, mysql

sing up to php site Encountering an error

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

the data base code

```
  -- Table structure for table `user`


CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `lname` text NOT NULL,
  `father` text NOT NULL,
  `username` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `flag` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `father`, `username`, `password`, `flag`) VALUES
(1, 'yasha', 'asadpoor', 'akbari', 'yashaaa', '123456', '1'),
(2, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1'),
(3, 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', '1');
```

Comment: you don´t have to set the id... it´s autoincrement!!!!

Comment: if id is your primary key,don't need to assign it in query,it will be incremented automatically.

Comment: if u did not set primary key auto incremented then set it then you don'nt need to give id.

Answer (score 2):

In order to take advantage of the auto-incrementing capability of the column, do not supply a value for that column when inserting rows. The database will supply a value for you.

`INSERT INTO user (name, lname, father, username, password, flag) VALUES
    ( 'yasha', 'asadpoor', 'akbari', 'yashaaa', '123456', '1'),
    ( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1'),
    ( 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', '1');`

view this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753371/how-to-insert-data-to-mysql-having-auto-incremented-primery-key).

Comment: You may want to be more specific about how the asker can use this information to solve their problem.

Comment: remove the from last line and update data base but The problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

change insert statement to

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `father`, `username`, `password`, `flag`) VALUES
(NULL,'yasha', 'asadpoor', 'akbari', 'yashaaa', '123456', '1'),
(NULL,'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '1'),
(NULL,'m', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', '1');
```