# Fail to insert data into mysql table using python script

Tags: python, mysql

i'm trying to insert data from my python script into my sql table. The script run with no error, however when i check in the table no data actually inserted. I have search around the internet and still couldn't figure out what is the problem. Any help would be very appreciated. Code below is what i've tried so far.

```
 ts = time.time()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="dummy_monke")
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()  # to point at database table
        queries = "INSERT INTO monitoring(id,lp,time) values (%s, %s, %s)"
        mycursor.execute(queries,spliced, timestamp)
        mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record updated successfully")

    except:
        mydb.rollback()
        print("record fail to update")
```

Comment: What is the content of `spliced`?

Comment: hi, spliced variable contain a license plate characters ( string)

Comment: Your `execute` parameters do not match your substitutions.  You have three substitutions,  so you need a tuple with 3 items to pass to execute.  You would have seen this if you had not included your blanket `try/except`.  You should NEVER include `try/except` until you have the code working.  Where does the `id` come from?

Comment: @TimRoberts the id is an auto increment attribute in the mysql table, do i need to include that in the INSERT statement? .

Comment: No, because you don't have a value for it.  The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8753410/19840609), you can do

```py
queries = "INSERT INTO monitoring(lp,time) values (%s, %s)"
mycursor.execute(queries, (spliced, timestamp))
```

to generate a tuple on the fly and have the auto-increment done for you.

Side note: it may make sense to rename `queries` to a singular `query`.

Comment: @ERENYEETGAR of course!