# Advice on structure of an archive table and use of AUTO_INCREMENT, with potential for reinsertion to original table

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with this structure, it contains thousands of rows and I query on this table regularly:

| Name | Type | Null | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| main_id (pk) | bigint(20) | No | AUTO_INCREMENT |
| order_id | bigint(20) | No |  |
| order_item_id | bigint(20) | No |  |
| order_date | date | No |  |

I want to **archive rows from this table into another table** periodically with PHP, I'll be creating another table with similar structure to this as the archive table.

Am I correct in thinking that the archive table `main_id` should be created **without** `AUTO_INCREMENT`? No rows will be added to this table except when PHP periodically grabs rows from the original table where the date is older than x and inserts them.

For future proofing, if I ever wanted to move the rows in the new archive table back to the original table, will the `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the original table cause an issue here? e.g. what happens if a `main_id` (e.g. 420) from the archive table goes in to the original table (where `main_id` might now be at 2000 for new rows)? will it reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert data to MySQL with auto-incremented column(field)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753371/how-to-insert-data-to-mysql-with-auto-incremented-columnfield)

Comment: @Stu I understand that if I don't provide main_id on insert it would auto increment, but would the archive table need AUTO_INCREMENT (so an identical clone of the original structure) or not use it?

Comment: No your archive table wouldn't use auto_increment, you want (presumably) an exact copy of the data.

Comment: @Stu and then in future if I ever wanted to insert the rows from archive table back to the original table these would be inserted with the main_id, and therefore wouldn't effect the AUTO_INCREMENT of new rows added to the original table, they would continue to be added to the original count?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` will only be used if the INSERT does not have any value given for that column. E.g. `INSERT INTO tbl (order_id, order_item_id, order_date) VALUES (....)`.  If from archive table, you insert records into main table WITH PK in the INSERT query, those values will be inserted as-is, and your AUTO-INCREMENT's current max value won't be affected.  I.e. `INSERT INTO tbl (main_id, order_id, order_item_id, order_date) VALUES (420, ....)` won't affect auto-increment status in any way. It will just try to insert a record with whatever value provided in the query.